# Infinite loop to read text file

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop, text-files

I am trying to read from a text file and print it to my GUI. The text file is being updated every 5 seconds from an outside source. I want to read this file (one line of 4 numbers) and update (overwrite) the previous entry in the text widget. I have been searching for hours and I can't seem to find a viable solution. Basically, push a button, start an infinite loop to read data from a text file, display that data in a text widget in my GUI, and repeat every 5 seconds, overwriting the old data in the widget with the new data.
Here is a snippet of my code so far:

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
import tkinter as Tk
import os
import time
starttime=time.time()
def exitProgram():
    print('I will now exit')
    root.destroy()
def runScript():
    print('I ran something')
    f = open("months.txt")
    two=Label(root, text=f.readlines(),bg='white',fg='blue')
    two.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
    two.config(font=("Courier",150))
    #time.sleep(5.0-((time.time()-starttime)%5.0))
```

Comment: You should use either multithreading or `root.after()`.

Comment: Do not use time.sleep in a tkinter program.  Use root.after.  Find multiple examples by searching SO for `[tkinter] root.after`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a file every five seconds, first create a function that will read the file once. Once you have that, you can write another function that will call that function every five seconds.

For example:

```
def run_periodically():
    runScript()
    root.after(5000, run_periodically)
```

You call this function once at startup and it will call `runScript`. It will then call itself in five seconds, will cause it to call `runScript` and call itself again in five seconds. This will run for the life of your program.

> I want to ... update (overwrite) the previous entry in the text widget.

I don't see a text widget, so I'm not completely sure about what you want to do. Assuming you mean a `Label` widget, you want to create the label widget just once and then use the `configure` method to change the value:

```
two=Label(root, text="", bg='white', fg='blue')
two.config(font=("Courier",150))
two.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

def runScript():
    print('I ran something')
    with open("months.txt") as f:
        data = f.read()
    two.configure(text=data)
```

Note: using the `with` statement guarantees that the file is closed after you are finished reading it.

Comment: When I say "text widget" I meant I am using a Label and displaying a "text". my "text" =readlines.

Comment: Finally had a chance to sit down and go through what you said to do. Works fantastic!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

This isn't set to a loop, but if you wanted to use a text or listbox it would give you options for deleting the field before re-reading the text document.

import tkinter

import time

from tkinter import *

root=tkinter.Tk()

root.title("This is my app")

lbox = Listbox(root, font='Helvetica -12')

lbox.pack()

open_file = open('c:\users\owner\desktop\digits.txt')

lbox.delete(0,END)  #Clears listbox

lbox.insert(END, open_file.readlines())  #reads and inserts text

root.mainloop()

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked.